# Unable to find valid certification path to requested target : Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, rest-assured

I am working on a test project where I'm automating GITHUB API's with Rest Assured using Eclipse and TestNG. The project runs perfectly from Eclipse as TestNG and also from command line using Maven build tool. But when I'm trying to run the project from Jenkins, I'm getting the following error :

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Try adding a `.relaxedHTTPSValidation()` and see if it works

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing issue when executing my jenkins pipeline which contains http block. When i used a free style job and execute the htpp step it was working fine. Finally i had to add `ignoreSslErrors: true` during the http call and it worked.